# How to loop quiz a certain amount of times and add lives, Java

Tags: java

I have a math quiz game I am making and I am not sure how to loop it, let's say 50 times. It ends after answering only 2 questions. I also want to add lives so after you get three questions wrong it ends the program. How am I able to do this?

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class Game {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);



    int Number1 =  (int)(20 * Math.random()) + 1;
    int Number2 =  (int)(20 * Math.random()) + 1;

    int correct = 0;


    System.out.print(Number1 + " + " + Number2 + " = ");
    int GuessRandomNumberAdd = keyboard.nextInt();

    if (GuessRandomNumberAdd == Number1 + Number2) {
    System.out.println("Correct!");
    correct++;
  }else {
    System.out.println("Wrong!");


  }
    System.out.print(Number1 + " * " + Number2 + " = ");    
    int GuessRandomNumberMul = keyboard.nextInt();

  if (GuessRandomNumberMul == Number1 * Number2) {
      System.out.println("Correct!");
      correct++;
  }else{
        System.out.println("Wrong!");




System.out.println("You got " + correct + " correct answers.");
```

Comment: Did you try a `for` loop like `for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)`?

Comment: @Prasad KarunagodaI did try that but the  'i < 50;'  part seems to double in the output

Comment: You have to ask the question (like `keyboard.nextInt()`) only once within this loop.

Answer (score 0):

After the int correct = 0;
add a lives counter.
eg:
int lives =3;
then start a while loop
while(lives > 0){

reduce the lives if a question is incorrect (where you put "wrong!" message)
lives--;

at the end of the while loop (before no of correct answers is printed out)
remember to put the last }

This will keep looping till you lose your lives

Answer (score 0):

A couple things:
-There are multiple java structures which allow you to loop. The main loops out there in any kind of programming language are for loop, while loop, and do-while loop (uncommon)
-You can create lives by defining a variable and checking it in every iteration (an iteration is each "run" through the code of a loop).

Your code after implementing this 2 things would look like this:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

public class Game {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    int Number1 =  (int)(20 * Math.random()) + 1;
    int Number2 =  (int)(20 * Math.random()) + 1;

    int correct = 0;
    int lives = 3;
    //The for loop is read as: having i equal 25 and the variable lives, iterate if i is lower than 25 AND lives is higher than 0. After an iteration, add 1 to i;
    for (int i=25, lives; i<25 && lives > 0; i++) {

    System.out.print(Number1 + " + " + Number2 + " = ");
    int GuessRandomNumberAdd = keyboard.nextInt();

    if (GuessRandomNumberAdd == Number1 + Number2) {
    System.out.println("Correct!");
    correct++;
  } else {
    System.out.println("Wrong!");
    lives--;
  }
    System.out.print(Number1 + " * " + Number2 + " = ");    
    int GuessRandomNumberMul = keyboard.nextInt();

  if (GuessRandomNumberMul == Number1 * Number2) {
      System.out.println("Correct!");
      correct++;
  }else{
        System.out.println("Wrong!");
        lives--;
  } //Forgot this bracket
} //Closes the for loop



System.out.println("You got " + correct + " correct answers.");
```

Answer (score 0):

See if below example works as you intend. Here I have given the loop count as 5. So there will be 5 "addition" questions and 5 "multiplication" questions.

I'm printing the question number also. So, now the output is more clear.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Game {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int correct = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      int Number1 = (int) (20 * Math.random()) + 1;
      int Number2 = (int) (20 * Math.random()) + 1;

      System.out.println("Question " + (i*2+1));
      System.out.print(Number1 + " + " + Number2 + " = ");
      int GuessRandomNumberAdd = keyboard.nextInt();

      if (GuessRandomNumberAdd == Number1 + Number2) {
        System.out.println("Correct!");
        correct++;
      }
      else {
        System.out.println("Wrong!");
      }
      System.out.println();

      System.out.println("Question " + (i*2+2));
      System.out.print(Number1 + " * " + Number2 + " = ");
      int GuessRandomNumberMul = keyboard.nextInt();

      if (GuessRandomNumberMul == Number1 * Number2) {
        System.out.println("Correct!");
        correct++;
      }
      else {
        System.out.println("Wrong!");
      }
      System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println("You got " + correct + " correct answers.");
  }
}
```